# "Continuous Integration"/deploying of node.js app to offline server

Tags: node.js

Our client has offline server (accessible only from inside of private network) and we have to deploy node.js application there (application consists of express web server and some workers and Postgres DB). We don't have access to that server so client will be preparing environment/installing app/performing updates on his own. Since server does not have access to internet, all npm packages (dependencies) have to be built on our side and delivered to the client as a package which can be easily installed by him. We have to also gather some logs and store them on the server.

My question is how to deal with such situation? At first I thought about docker - I could just provide image for the client with all environment configured inside - however docker seems to work nicely only with registers/repos and all "online stuff" - to provide raw image for client I would have to send min. 670MB file each time to the client.

Till now in our company we used everything in cloud (mostly on heroku) - web servers, workers, databases, logs and so on and it was easy to manage such stack (plus source on github and automatic deploys by travis)...

Comment: How about keeping things simple and deploying through source control like git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [offline-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-npm)

You can save my all packages with single command

```
npm install -g offline-npm
```

After saving successfully installing offline is real ease like

```
npm install [-g] <name>-<version>.tgz
```

Comment: NPM now has this inbuilt. `npm pack`. Refer for docs - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/pack.html